# $a^2-b^2=37$, evaluate $ a^2+b^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $a^2-b^2=37$ and also a and b are integers, can we evaluate $a^2+b^2$ possible values? Are those many or just some? I found that  $a^2+b^2$ can be only $685$. But how to prove it? I just guessed, but can we somehow evaluate it?

Comment: so $(a+b)(a-b)=37$, and $37 $ is prime, so $a+b=?$, $a-b=?$, $a=?$, $b=?$, $a^2+b^2=?$

Comment: That is a remarkable guess.

Comment: Prime factorization; b can't be zero

Comment: Indeed: $361+324=685$ :-)

Comment: I don't think there is any other way than noting that $a^2-b^2$ factors, 37 is prime and figuring the only choices of $a,b$.  I feel bad about these questions as the require either insight of familiarity with similar and neither can be taught.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am just building upon J.W. Tanner's comment and posting it as an answer.

Your equation can be rewritten as $(a+b)(a-b)=37$ and since 37 is prime we have four cases.

Case $1$ : $a+b=37$ and $a-b=1$ $\Rightarrow a = 19,\ b=18$ 
Case $2$ : $a+b=1$ and $a-b=37$ $\Rightarrow a = 19,\ b=-18$ 
Case $3$ : $a+b=-37$ and $a-b=-1$ $\Rightarrow a = -19,\ b=-18$ 
Case $4$ : $a+b=-1$ and $a-b=-37$ $\Rightarrow a = -19,\ b=18$

In all cases, $a^2 + b^2 = 361 + 324 = 685$

Answer (score 9):

The product of $a+b$ and $a-b$ is $37$, and since $37$ is prime,

we must have one factor $1$ and the other $37,$ or one factor $-1$ and the other $-37$.

Now solve for $a$ and $b$ in each of these cases and see what $a^2+b^2$ is.

Answer (score 9):

Casework can be avoided as follows:

It has already been noted that 37 is a prime, and $(a+b)(a-b) = 37$ for integers $a,b$ implies that $\{ |a-b|, |a+b|\} = \{1 , 37\}$.

Then $$a^2+b^2 = \frac{|a-b|^2+|a+b|^2}{2} = \frac{1^2+37^2}{2} = \boxed{685}$$

Comment: Why isn't $\{ |a-b|, |a+b|\} = \{37 , 1\}$ valid?

Comment: @GameTimeWithAryan It is valid. Note that when you represent a set by listing all its elements, the order does not matter. Particularly, $\{1,37\} = \{37,1\}$. Maybe you are confusing it with the $\Bbb R^2$ vector $(1,37)$.

Comment: I think case work can be avoided also by stating "WOLOG we may assume $a,b\in \mathbb N$".  Of course, one of my peeves are folks who state wolog when not making it clear why we can wolog.  In this case as our only concern is with the squares of $a$ and $b$ we can simply assume we use that positive values. (We could just as well have $a=-19$ and $b=+18$)

Answer (score 2):

I present an alternative.  It is not as good an alternative.  In fact I would say this is a *bad* way to solve.  But I want to impress that if one doesn't always see the correct insight one can still chew an answer and there is *always* more than one way to do things.

$a^2 -b^2 =37$ so $a^2 > b^2$ and if we assume $a,b$ are positive integers (we might as well, whether they are negative of positive their squares are positive and we are only answering questions about their squares) then $a > b$.  Let $d = a-b$ so $a=b+d$.

Then we have $a^2 -b^2 = (b+d)^2 - b^2 = 2bd + d^2 = 37$.

We see that $d^2 < 2bd + d^2 =37$ so $d= 6,5,4,3,2,1$ and we can test each value.  If that is too much work, we can see that $2bd$ is even and $37$ is odd so $d$ is odd and we can test $d = 5,3, 1$.  If that is still too much work we can not that $d|d^2$ and also $2bd$ so $d|2bd +d^2 = 37$.  But $37$ is prime so $d=1$.

And so $2bd + d^2 = 2b + 1=37$ and $b=18$.  ANd $a = b+d = 18+1=19$.

Which.... if we were *really* paying attention we might have noticed we were skirting the other better way of doing it.  We noted that $d|2bd +d^2$ but as $d =b-a$ and $2bd+d^2 = a^2 -b^2$ we are noting that $a-b|a^2-b^2$ and as $\frac {2bd + d^2}d = 2b + d = b + (b+d) = b + a = a +b$ we were really just doing the same thing as everyone else.

Comment: I think from "$a^2-b^2=(b+d)^2-b^2=2bd+d^2=37$" also has the simplification at the right of $d*(2b+d)=37$.  Since $a^2+b^2$ can be evaluated with **Case 1:** $a>0, b>0$ or **Case 2** $a<0, b<0$, **Each Case yielding the same answer** for $a^2+b^2$. Hence, start with all natural numbers $d>0$ and $2b+d>0$, as possible natural prime factors of $37$.  Clearly with $(2b+d)$ as a natural number $(2b+d)>d$.  With $(2b+d)$ as a greater natural number factor and $d$ as a lesser natural number factor, it follows that $d=1$.  And also $2b+1=37 \implies b=18$ and $a=b+d=19$. Then $a^2+b^2=18^2+19^2=685$!

Comment: I did not yet create an edit with the previous comment, but I would appreciate if someone like the author or someone else edits the original posts the the above shortcut, since comments can be easily deleted and posts not-so.  I do not want to offend the original contributor who helped so much so I have decided not to edit his work.  Now with the comment, I am giving this answer also an up-vote since it is an original perspective towards the question and answer.

Comment: @StephenElliott I don't understand the purpose of either of you comments.  I think it compounds things to consider insignificant cases when they can be explained as insignificant with a "wolog" expression (hence my parenthetical.  And knowing that $d|37=2bd+d^2$ doesn't require expressing the other factor, $2b+d$ and evaluating it as larger than $d$ when we know $d \le 6 < 37$.  From that alone it follows $d=1$.

Answer (score 1):

To restate the question for clarity:

$$
\boxed{
\text{Given }a^2-b^2=37\text{ and }a\text{ and }b\text{ are integers; Then, evaluate }a^2+b^2
.}\tag{Eq. 1}$$
Add $b^2$ to both the left and the right of Equation 1, and solve for $a^2$ in terms of $b^2$, and then sum $a^2$ and $b^2$ so:
$$
a^2=b^2+37 \underset{implies}\implies a^2+b^2=(b^2+37)+b^2 = 2*b^2+37
\tag{Eqs. 2}
$$
Alternatively, given a value of $a^2$ it is possible to determine also $a^2+b^2$ in terms of $a^2$ as follows.  Subtract from the left of Equations 2 the value $37$, so that:
$$
b^2=a^2-37 \underset{implies}\implies a^2+b^2=a^2+(a^2-37)=2*a^2-37
\tag{Eqs. 3}
$$
So given any value for $a^2$ or $b^2$, it is possible to find the value for $a^2+b^2$ (from Equations 2 and Equations 3) as:
$$
\text{Given }a\text{ then }a^2+b^2=2*a^2-37
\text{ or } 
\text{Given }b\text{ then }a^2+b^2=2*b^2+37
\tag{Eqs. 4}
$$
Now comes the restriction that $a$ and $b$ are integers. Given $a$,Equations 4 on the left imply:
$$
(b-a)(b+a)=-37 \underset{implies}\implies (a-b)(a+b)=37
\tag{Eq. 5}
$$
But $37$ is **prime!**, meaning it **can be factored by** $1$ **and itself** $37$, according to the [definition of a prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011984/what-is-the-definition-of-prime-number):

> That would lose the useful idea of a prime number. We could also say
> that 1/2 is a factor of 5. So we restrict the possible factors to
> positive integers.

The question has that $a$ and $b$ **are integers** and thus can be positive or negative. However, if $a>0$ then also $b>0$.  And if $a<0$ then also $b<0$ so as to preserve the property that $((a+b)*(a-b)=37)>0$.

In either case, the factor $(a+b)$ can be assigned a value, and then it follows what the value for $(a-b)$ is.  **Case 1:**  For instance, when $(a+b)>0$ set $(a+b)=37$, since here $(a+b)>(a-b)$. So that $(a+b)*(a-b)>0$ and $((a+b)>0) \underset{implies}\implies (a-b)>0$ also, set $(a-b)=1$.

Alternatively, there is this **Case 2:** $(a+b)<0$ and $(a-b)<0$ so that $((a+b)*(a-b)>0)=37$, when $(a+b)<0$ set $(a+b)=-37$, since here $(a+b)<(a-b)$. So that $(a+b)*(a-b)>0$, also set $(a-b)=-1$.

Now we seek an identity for $a^2+b^2$ in terms of $a+b$ and $a-b$.  Consider:

$$\frac{(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2}{2}=\frac{(a^2+2*a*b+b^2)+(a^2-2*a*b+b^2)}{2}=\frac{(a^2+b^2+2*a*b+b^2)}{2}+\frac{(a^2+b^2-2*a*b+b^2)}{2}
=a^2+b^2
\tag{Eqs. 6}$$
This is the identity needed, namely $a^2+b^2=\frac{(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2}{2}$ and this identity does not depend on the sign of $(a+b)$ or of $(a-b)$ even **since both quantities are squared!**

So, finally,
$$
\boxed{
a^2+b^2=\frac{37*37+1*1}{2}=\frac{1369+1*1}{2}==\frac{1370}{2}=685
}
\tag{Eqs. 7}
$$